# How to install VPython on Python 3.6 (python distribution)?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino-ide, vpython

I want to get Vpython on Python 3.6(Python Distribution). I couldn't find an option except for anaconda. Please help because I want to process the data coming from Arduino to Python making 3D visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

See [VPython's website](http://vpython.org) for install options and how the new VPython differs from the older classic VPython. The new VPython works with python 3.6. The old classic VPython works only with python 2.x.. If you have the old classic VPython on your computer then you might need to uninstall it first. Then install the new VPython version 7 with pip.

```
pip install VPython
```

Then launch IDLE or spyder python IDE and try running this simple program:

```
from VPython import *

box()
```

You should see a 3d canvas with a box appear in your webb browser.

Comment: I got the box and when I try to rotate the box using mouse nothing happens. It seems it is a 2D image of a box.